# A problem on Constrained Motion

Tags: calculus, physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

Q. A particle is moving in a smooth curve under gravity and its velocity varies as the actual distance from the highest point. Prove that the curve is a cycloid.

Attempt:
The eq. of motion is
$$v\frac{dv}{ds}=-g\sin{\psi}, ~~~~~~~~~~\frac{v^2}{\rho}=g\cos{\psi}$$

Given, $v=Cs$,$C=constant.$ I have to show that the path is a cycloid which is of the form $s=4a \sin(\psi)$. First eq implies $\sin{\psi}=-C^2s/g$.

2nd eq gives, $C^2s^2d\psi=g\cos{\psi}~ds$ i.e $-1/C^2\times\frac{1}{s}=1/g ~~ln(sec\psi+tan\psi) +C$ (Since, $\rho=\frac{ds}{d\psi}$)

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: I have removed my answer until I resolve the $\rho$ I didn't read that part.

Comment: @Chinny84 yes, $\rho=\frac{ds}{d\psi}$

Comment: are you sure you require that you have $s = 4a\sin psi$ and not some other form? is that the exact answer? since putting in the solution above you can not solve the ode.I have found some solution but it is not the same as the above.

Comment: @Chinny84 Equation of cycloid may come in other form. Please post your answer.

Comment: Hi there, sorry about my delay ( I have a lot of things going on at the moment). I did take a look at the problem again, but I am confused about going about a solution as I get something vastly different. Also, I would like to add could you describe that this are the first set of equations you have derived? since you get the form $s = 4a\sin \psi$ from the first equation once you set $v = Cs$.?